# UIButton not working loaded in a child ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uikit, uiresponder

I've got a `MainViewController` where I'm loading a slideout-menu. The MainViewController contains a static `TopView` and a `ContentView` where different child controllers or views are loaded, depending on which menu entry was selected.

There is a button inside one of the children is loaded, but it is not working. 
When I start the app with the ViewController including the button, set to "is initial View Controller", everything works properly.

When starting the app with the `MainViewController` as initial View Controller with a loaded child, the button is not working (it is loaded in the view, but not reacting).
Any suggestions how I can make this work?

**MainViewController loading of Child View**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, SideBarDelegate {
var contentView = UIView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ....
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 174/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1)
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusBarView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

}

func sideBarDidSelectButtonAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
    ...       
    if index == 0{
        statusBarLabel.text = "First"
        let controller:FirstViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! FirstViewController
        controller.view.frame = ContentView.bounds
        controller.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
        contentView.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        print("touched index 0")
    } else if index == 1{
        // index is 1
    }
}
```

**FirstViewController**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let addButton = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)

        addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 60)
        addButton.clipsToBounds = true
        addButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 204/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
        addButton.setTitle("add feed", for: .normal)
        addButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
        self.view.addSubview(AddButton)
        addButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpAddButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDownAddButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)

    func touchUpAddButton() {
        addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 204/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
    }

    func touchDownAddButton() {
        addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 174/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your functions to these

```
func TouchUpAddButton(sender: UIButton){
    addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 204/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)

}

func TouchDownAddButton(sender: UIButton) {
    addButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 174/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

And change your code of adding the target to

```
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.touchUpAddButton(_:)), for: .touchDown)
addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.touchDownAddButton(_:)), for: .touchDown)
```

Comment: and sender would be the button which can be changed instead of `addButton`

Comment: Thats right, you can change AddButton to sender inside the touchUp and touchDown functions.

Comment: it's still not working, now it gives me an error while compiling: use of unresolved identifier 'TouchUpAddButton'

Comment: Did you change the code to what I have? With the (sender: UIButton) at the end of the function? That error is saying it can't see the TouchUpAddButton function

Comment: yes, i did excatly change the code like you told, so putting (sender: UIButton) for both functions and changing the selector to (_:)

Comment: Hmmm, what does the autocomplete look like? when your typing the add target methods. AddButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(T <--- What does Xcode show as autocomplete when you type the "o" here?

Comment: TouchUpAddButton(sender:)

Comment: sry but it's still not working, i don't know what's wrong, i mean it gives me no error now, but the button is still not working

Answer (score 0):

While adding the view in the container you don't have to use addSubview function, that the FirstViewController functionality is not working.

Use below code:

```
let newViewController:FirstViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "First") as! FirstViewController
let oldViewController  = childViewControllers.last! as UIViewController
    oldViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    addChildViewController(newViewController)
    transition(from: oldViewController, to: newViewController, duration: 0.25, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations:{ () -> Void in
        // nothing needed here
    }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        oldViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
        newViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    })
```

You can change the duration, it used for animation

Comment: I have to add it as a subwiew, as there are two views in my MainViewController, the TopView and the ContentView (that's where i want to add my First- and SecondViewController). Or do i don't get your solution right?

Comment: Is your ContentView is kind of UIContainerView? for replacing the view in MainViewController used UIContainerView, it will work perfectly instead of UIView

Answer (score 0):

**First solution:**

Remove an autolayout constrains

**Second solution:**

Button is not performing an action because a child view controller view should be added directly to a container controller view (in your case: *MainViewController* view) and not via an intermediate view (in your case: *contentView*)